# Opening a Sphere Mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm planning an animation, and one of the creatures is going to basically have a mouth. It'll be roughly spherical, but... unlike most of the ones you are thinking of, I want the opening to 'bend open' the sphere.

Okay, I'm not sure that's how I'd describe it, but... think Pac-man, then think THIS:[image: Chuxtoepose_The_Magnificent]

That 'thing/eldritch horror' is known as Chuxtoepose. It's from [this game](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/25857420/) and I want to make that magnificent jaw by cutting into a UV Sphere. Is this doable, and how?

Thanks, Nefer

Comment: cutting open the sphere is going to be the easy part. Decide which ring you want to base the mouth at, select the desired vertices, and rip the edges. The other parts, how to deal with the teeth, and animating the bits after ripping are going to be the challenge, it seems to me.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Rip the edges... what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: {select them in edit mode and hit [v]}

Comment: I think the title is a bit off. Could you please find a better one?

Comment: @poor: I actually changed the title twice. First it was Creating a Mouth from a Sphere, then Making a Mouth out of a Sphere, and then I simplified it. But it's closed anyways.

Comment: gosh darnit you answered both my questions! Hold on as I upvote your recent activity... Can I flag down a mod for help here, because brasshat solved the jaw and cegatron solved the actual maw, but I can only give one answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your UV sphere in edit mode, select the segments on the ring that you want as the location of your mouth, thus:

[image: Rip_01]

then press the <kbd>V</kbd> key, which creates a new set of vertices, like this:

[image: rip_02]

You can also do it manually, but deleting an edge perpendicular to the ring at which you want to locate your mouth, duplicating the vertex on the "mouth" end of the deleted edge, and connecting the duplicated vertex to the vertices in the ring above.

Answer (score 3):

Create a sphere, move the pivot point to the point where you want the mouth to open.

[image]

Duplicate. On one sphere delete the top half. On the other delete the lower half.

[image]
Animate both objects by rotating them in opposite directions.

[image]

Optionally create a cycle by extrapolating the keyframes in the curve editor (Channel->Extrapolate->Make cyclic).

Add an empty and parent both hemispheres to it.

To move the object just move the empty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like your little gif animation :)